# selecting elements in an array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix like

```
A = 
[ 10 20;
  30 40;
  50 60 ]
```

also I have a vector like

```
idx = 
[ 2; 1; 1]
```

which means that I want

the second column (=20) in the first row,

the first column (=30) in the second row, and

the first column (=50) in the third row.

How can I end up with a vector with [20; 30 ; 50]?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SUB2IND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) function;

```
result = A(sub2ind(size(A),(1:numel(idx))',idx));
```

For some performance improvement you can substitute SUB2IND manually computing the linear indices:

```
linidx = (1:numel(idx))' + (idx - 1).*size(A,1);
result = A(linidx);
```

In any case make sure `numel(idx)` doesn't exceed number of matrix rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [ 10 20; 30 40; 50 60 ]
idx = [ 2; 1; 1]
t =(idx==2)*2 + idx
t1 = (idx==1)
A( t+ (t1 .* [0:2]'))
```

Output

```
ans =
 20
 30
 50
```

Now use general numbers and it will fit any other dimensions.